# How to get index value for a cell in order to reference a sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a UI to easily access data from other sheets. The sheet names are the years from 2009-2019, and I have a drop down list in one of the cells that I want to use as a reference to the particular sheet I want to use.

I've seen people using the `=indirect()` function but I was not able to get it to work

What works:

```
=INDEX('2009'!C1:C100,C26)
```

What doesn't work:

```
=INDEX(indirect("C11")!C1:C100,C26)
```

where `C11` is the value of the drop-down menu

Any help would be appreciated as I do not have very much experience with google sheets.

- source sheet: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15FWZlYko4mxAWWB1NbAP5UBds_yKdA-zbdPqMHpwN5M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because `indirect("C11")!C1:C100` is not a valid range. try:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(C11&"!C1:C100"), C26)
```

[image]